# I want to display only Display Name than Display Name with Mail ID

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have created a web service(Windows server 2018 R2 enterprise) where I send mail using the code

```
public void SendMail(string f, string t, string subject, string body)
{
    System.Web.Mail.MailMessage Message = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
    Message.From = f;
    Message.To = t;
    Message.Subject = subject;
    Message.Body = body;
    Message.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
    System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.Company.com";
    System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(Message);
}
```

When mail triggered from Address is like "Suresh Kukka" (display name)

if I Use the same code hosting same web service (Windows Server 2016 Standard) I am getting mail from address like "suresh.kukka@company.com"

I have used new code like below (web service hosted in Windows Server 2016 Standard)

```
public void SendMail(string f, string t, string subject, string body)
{ 
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    string[] name = f.Split('@');
    string[] mainname = name[0].Split('.');
    string DisplayName = mainname[0] + " " + mainname[1];
    TextInfo _textinfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    DisplayName = _textinfo.ToTitleCase(DisplayName);
    // Message.From = f;
    MailAddress address = new MailAddress(f, DisplayName);
    Message.From = address;


    Message.To.Add(t);
    Message.Subject = subject;
    Message.Body = body;
    Message.IsBodyHtml = true;


    SmtpClient objclint = new SmtpClient();
    objclint.EnableSsl = true;
    objclint.Port = 25;
    objclint.Host = "smtp.company.com";
    objclint.Send(Message);
    Message.Dispose();
```

}

here I am getting mail From address like Suresh Kukka leq suresh.kukka@company.com geq  but i want the from addrees like "Suresh Kukka" only.. can anybody help me this

Comment: Applying SSL binding to web service solved my problem. ha ha some times we miss very basic things

Answer (score 0):

Applying SSL binding to web service solved my problem. ha ha some times we miss very basic things –